# Heroku: Run Rails Application with PHP Script?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I have a rails application that uses php code. I am calling the php code directly with a system call 'php path/to/script.php'

This works fine on my local machine where I have php installed. I'm looking to deploy this to somewhere like Heroku. To solve this problem, I am using the multibuildpack Github library:

github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi

I have specified in my .buildpacks

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php.git
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git

and both install just fine. The problem is that Heroku treats the application like a php application. On the Heroku logs, it states that it is using the php configuration and is starting php-fpm when I want it to run as a rails application.

How do I go about fixing this? Specifically, how do I make sure that php is ready on Heroku when I make the system call

Comment: That might be a weird question but.. why do you mix two completely different languages like ruby and php? Can't you rewrite the script to ruby?

Comment: Its an existing library. I could rewrite the entire library in Ruby but that would take an incredibly long time considering there are 30+ files.

Comment: If there is library to do something in php then almost certainly there is its ruby equivalent and if not then it could be achieved some other way. Could you try to explain what exactly this library does? :)

Comment: Its the PHP routeboxer implementation on Github. 
https://github.com/bazo/route-boxer

Although there are only 4 files there are dependencies that would need to be installed and translated as well.

Comment: I ended up deploying on a VPS to fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using multiple buildpacks

```
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/php --index 1 -a app-name
```

Also create a composer.json file on the root of your project, you can even specify the php version like this:

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.4",
    "ext-mcrypt": ">=2.5.8"
  }
}
```

Finally create a composer.lock with

```
php composer.phar update --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Commit, deploy your code and all set.

Answer (score 0):

If PHP CLI is installed you could use the gem "php_process", which I wrote, to call the PHP library instead of bundling PHP files, which may be what is causing Heroku to define your project as using PHP.

https://github.com/kaspernj/php_process

Comment: Interesting.... so how would I go about calling a php script with this? And how can I get the return value of said PHP script? I'm using the library but I've also modified some functions in the library to suit my needs.

Comment: I could write examples on how to call various things with PhpProcess here on StackOverflow, but that stuff is already on the Github README of PhpProcess. But basically you would rewrite the script (not the library) to Ruby, but using the library through PhpProcess.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a way to fix this because according to Heroku - they support both languages and determine which language is used in the application. It seems it's one language or the other.

I write PHP and have dabbled with Ruby on Heroku, but haven't tried mixing the two. It sounds a lot messier than I would be comfortable with, personally.

Why not try contacting Heroku Support?